# (Angular 6) Pass value from a method to another

Tags: angular, methods

I'm working in an Angulat App, when clicking a button, and calling a method, i need some info to be passed to another method (or the global variable's value). This is the idea:

```
<tr (click)="select(data.id)" *ngFor="let data of User">
```

When i click this, i'm sending the id to the 'select' method, which will run some jquery and make that specific option gray. When doing this, i need the 'data.id' to be passed as the value of a global variable. This happens because i have a button 'EDIT', which will use this id

Here is the button:

```
<a (click)='redirect()' id="edt">
```

And these are the methods:

```
Data: number;

select(data: number) //this is the data.id
{
  $("tr#body").click(function(){
    $("tr#body").css({
      'background-color' : 'transparent'
    })
    $(this).css({
      'background-color' : 'rgba(0,0,0,.2)'
    })
  })

this.Data = data;

}

redirect(){
  this.router.navigateByUrl('Someurl/' + Data)
}
```

I need 'redirect' to use the data from 'select', my idea of doing this was defining a global variable called 'Data' and try to save the local's 'data' value by using something like

> this.Data = data;

But the global variable Data never gets the value from 'select'. How am I supposed to do this?

OBS: I cannot call the method 'redirect' from 'select', because 'EDIT' is not the only method that might want to use the Id's value

Comment: Holy Mother of God, why are you using jQuery in Angular?

Comment: `will run some jquery` please stop using jQuery with Angular.

Comment: can you please just help me with my problem?

Comment: In `redirect()` change to `this.Data`. Everything else seems fine.

Comment: Still doen't work

Comment: select  method working properly, and you getting id in select method parameter ?

Comment: yes, when i console.log(data) inside the 'select', the id is working fine

Comment: You can use plain javascript using document.getElementById('edit').click() to redirect after setting the Data.

Answer (score 1):

i think then you write something like

```
redirect(){
 // this.router.navigateByUrl('Someurl/' + this.Data);
 this.router.navigate(['Someurl', this.Data]);
 // both way you can do it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by putting the ID's value into a cookie and calling it later.
It's not the nicest thing to do, but it works.

```
this.cookieService.set('ID', data);
```